# How to upgrade PHP 7.0 to 7.1 in Ubuntu (offline server)?

Tags: upgrade, lubuntu, php

I need to upgrade PHP 7.0 to 7.1. I am using Ubuntu 16.04 in Linux server. I searched that need to use `ondrej` package to upgrade. But my trial failed. Is it because my server is not connected to internet? If yes, is there any way to do it offline?

I had download these files as suggested:
[downloaded files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oOhiD.png)

Is this the right files to be used? Where to put this files in the server? Is there any specific directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After days of searching, trying with errors using various sources with others' help, I managed to solve the problem using this solution:

1. Open directory

   sudo nano /etc/apt/apt.conf
2. Enter proxy server url setting

   Acquire::http::Proxy “http://username:password@proxy_url:port”;
3. Open directory

   sudo nano /etc/environment
4. Type in proxies:

   http_proxy=http://username:password@proxy_url:port/
    httsp_proxy=https://username:password@proxy_url:port/
    ftp_proxy=”http://username:password@proxy_url:port/”

After configuring the proxies setting, I manage to update php using normal command using ondrej.

Thank you to all of you for your suggestions and solutions.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this out:

- Add ppa

  ```
  sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
  ```
- Update apt list

  ```
  sudo apt update
  ```
- Install php 7.1

  ```
  sudo apt install php7.1 php7.1-common
  ```
- Remove Php 7.0

  ```
  sudo apt purge php7.0 php7.0-common
  ```

**Note**: Before doing anything if you have apache server running then make sure to stop its service. To stop its service use the command `service apache2 stop`

Comment: it gives error cannot add PPA:~ondrej/ubuntu/php. ondrej user or team does not exist

Comment: are u using proxy server?

Comment: yes..does it has different configuration?

Comment: refer this post: https://askubuntu.com/questions/724224/cant-add-ppa-on-ubuntu-15-10-user-or-team-does-not-exist

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you can download all required deb packages from this URL (I assumed that you are using 16.04 64 bits).

https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/ubuntu/php/+build/16264601

To know which packages to download, you can use this command to display all php7.0 packages installed on the server.

```
dpkg -l | grep php7.0
```

Copy the files on to an USB drive, mount the drive on the offline server, and then use the following command (don't use dpkg):

```
apt install ./php7.1_vvv.deb ./php7.1-common_vvv.deb  ./php7.1-mmm_vvv.deb ...
```

Replace vvv by the version and mmm by module name, use tab to use the auto-completion. Here an example with php7.1 and mysql.

apt install ./php7.1_7.1.26-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1_all.deb ./php7.1-common_7.1.26-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1_amd64.deb ./php7.1-mysql_7.1.26-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1_amd64.deb

Comment: i see that the ubuntu version is 18.04..can it be used for ubuntu 16.04?

Comment: I just found this package..https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/ubuntu/php/+packages?field.name_filter=&field.status_filter=published&field.series_filter=xenial. Is this the right one to be downloaded? It contains a long list of files..do I need to download all?

Comment: I just edited my question according to @olivierb2 suggestion, how to proceed to the next step, to install in server?

Comment: I stored in /etc/php and write command apt install but get segmentation fault error