# How to upgrade to newest version of git - Cannot add PPA error

Tags: ppa, git, launchpad

I am trying to use the package manager to upgrade to the newest version of git. When I try a simple apt-get install, it says my version is the newest version (1:2.7.4), which clearly is not the newest version.

I tried running the command to access the newest version from this repository, but I get this error:

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:git-core/ppa
Cannot add PPA: 'ppa:~git-core/ubuntu/ppa'.
ERROR: '~git-core' user or team does not exist.
```

Any advice here on why I would be getting this error, and how to upgrade to the newest version (apart from building from source)

Comment: Using this exact command `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:git-core/ppa` I have no problem adding this ppa.

Comment: Yes, I realize that - that is why I am asking if anyone knows why it tells me the user does not exist.

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: Could your issue be [proxy related](https://askubuntu.com/questions/724224/cant-add-ppa-on-ubuntu-15-10-user-or-team-does-not-exist)?